# RavenDB fails with ConcurrencyException when using new transaction

Tags: ravendb

This code always fails with a ConcurrencyException:

```
    [Test]
    public void EventOrderingCode_Fails_WithConcurrencyException()
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (var scope1 = new TransactionScope())
        using (var session = DataAccess.NewOpenSession)
        {
            session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
            session.Advanced.AllowNonAuthoritativeInformation = false;
            var ent1 = new CTEntity
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = "George"
            };
            using (var scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {

                session.Store(ent1);
                session.SaveChanges();
                scope2.Complete();
            }
            var ent2 = session.Load<CTEntity>(id);
            ent2.Name = "Gina";
            session.SaveChanges();
            scope1.Complete();
        }
    }
```

It fails at the last session.SaveChanges. Stating that it is using a NonCurrent etag. If I use Required instead of RequiresNew for scope2 - i.e. using the same Transaction. It works.

Now, since I load the entity (ent2) it should be using the newest Etag unless this is some cached value attached to scope1 that I am using (but I have disabled Caching). So I do not understand why this fails.

I really need this setup. In the production code the outer TransactionScope is created by NServiceBus, and the inner is for controlling an aspect of event ordering. It cannot be the same Transaction.

And I need the optimistic concurrency too - if other threads uses the entity at the same time.

BTW: This is using Raven 2.0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else have answered, I had better give it a go myself.

It turns out this was a human error. Due to a bad configuration of our IOC container the DataAccess.NewOpenSession gave me the same Session all the time (across other tests). In other words Raven works as expected :)

Before I found out about this I also experimented with using TransactionScopeOption.Suppress instead of RequiresNew. That also worked. Then I just had to make sure that whatever I did in the suppressed scope could not fail. Which was a valid option in my case.